# How to get document ids from FT.AGGREGATE with Redisearch?

Tags: redisearch

I would like to aggregate documents and returns only document ids.

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With aggregate you sometimes may return results which has nothing to do with document id (for example if you group by some field and then return the groups sizes). This is why the aggregate result do not contains the document id. If your specific aggregation does preserve the document id then it is possible to put it inside the document itself as a none indexed field and then return it.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE idx SCHEMA name TEXT SORTABLE docid TAG SORTABLE NOINDEX
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD idx doc1 1.0 FIELDS name name1 docid doc1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD idx doc2 1.0 FIELDS name name2 docid doc2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD idx doc3 1.0 FIELDS name name1 docid doc3
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.AGGREGATE idx * GROUPBY 1 @name REDUCE TOLIST 1 @docid as docids
1) (integer) 2
2) 1) name
   2) "name2"
   3) docids
   4) 1) "doc2"
3) 1) name
   2) "name1"
   3) docids
   4) 1) "doc1"
      2) "doc3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Most of the time I need to return document id for my aggregate queries. I already though about duplicating document id in a 'sortable' field (adding memory overhead) but I was expecting that redisearch would give access to document @id when aggregating data. It seems that it is not currently supported (v1.4.2). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Math, If you select an answer as correct, please up-vote it. If it is good, but if it does not solve your problem, up-vote it, but do not mark it as an answer, since some-one else may be able to provide a correct an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of RediSearch, the expression `LOAD {nargs} {property}` allows loading the document id using `@__key`, which can be referenced in later stages of the aggregate pipeline:

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx * LOAD 1 @__key GROUPBY 1 @type REDUCE TOLIST 1 @__key as keys
```